# Expected number of rolls in craps conditional on the fact that the house wins.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm currently trying to find the expected number of rolls in a craps game given that the house wins. In a craps game, two fair 6 sided die are rolled. The sum of both is then calculated. If the sum is $2, 3$ or $12$, then the house wins. If the sum is $7$ or $11$, the player wins. If another number $m$ is rolled, ie, not $2, 3, 7, 11$ or $12$, then the die are rolled again and again until $7$ or $m$ comes up. At this point, if $7$ comes up, then the house wins, "craps out". If $m$ comes up, then the player wins.

I am trying to find the expected number of rolls given that the house wins. The way I set it up is:

$$
\text{E(number of rolls given house wins)} = 2\cdot P( \text{rolling} \ 2,3,12,7,11 \ \text{on 1st roll}) \cdot P(\text{roll} \  7  \ \text{on 2nd roll}) + 3 \cdot P( \text{rolling} \ 2,3,12,7,11 \ \text{on 1st roll}) \cdot P(\text{roll neither 7 or $m$ on 2nd roll}) \cdot P(\text{roll 7 on 3rd roll}) + \cdots
$$

The problem here is that there is that pesky $m$ in $P(\text{roll neither 7 or $m$ on 2nd roll})$. I am not sure how to deal with this. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ denote the conditional expectation you are after and let
$\mu_{m}$ denote the conditional expectation of number of rolls yet
to come after a first undeciding roll.

Also $p_{k}$ denotes the unconditional probability to throw sum $k$, so $p_{k}=\frac{6-\left|k-7\right|}{36}$.

Then:

$$\mu=1+\sum_{m\in\left\{ 4,5,6,8,9,10\right\} }\frac{p_{m}\mu_{m}}{1-p_{7}-p_{11}}$$

The $\mu_{m}$ can be calculated on base of the following equalities
for $m\in\left\{ 4,5,6,8,9,10\right\} $:

$$\mu_{m}=1+\frac{24+\left|m-7\right|}{30+\left|m-7\right|}\mu_{m}$$

leading to:$$\mu_{m}=5+\frac{1}{6}\left|m-7\right|$$

Here we are working under the condition that $m$ (the result of the
first undeciding roll) does not come up (so the house wins).